# An integral growth condition implies Hölder continuity

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $f$ be in $L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. If for all $x,x_0$ and for all $r>0$ we have $$\frac{1}{m(B_r(x_0))}\int_{B_r(x_0)}|f(x)-f(x_0)|\,dx < C\cdot r^{\alpha} $$
where $C$ doesn't depend on $x,x_0$ or $r$. Then $f\in C^{0,\alpha}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.

One can see that the set of points for a given $x_0$ for which the Hölder condition doesn't hold is an open set. But this may not be enough to cause a contradiction in the bound of the integral in the RHS.

Comment: Are you sure it is $r^\alpha$ and not $r^{n+\alpha}$ in the right-hand side of the inequality?

Comment: could you specify what exactly your question is?

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Not that it's  clear to me that either version is true, but I suspect the extra $r^n$ you want is taken care of by the $1/m(B)$ on the left side...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first I doubted this was so, but in fact it's trivial. Since this smells like a homework problem, a **sketch:**

Say $r=|x-y|$. Note that $$|f(x)-f(y)|=\frac1{m(B_r(x))}\int_{B_r(x)}|f(x)-f(y)|\,dt.$$Now use the fact that $$|f(x)-f(y)|\le|f(x)-f(t)|+|f(y)-f(t)|$$and note that $B_r(x)\subset B_{2r}(y)$.